# Webdriver automatically clears Text (Autosuggested text)entered in TextBox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

WebDriver can identify the Text box.
WebDriver can pass the value through SendText to the Correct Textbox.
But the entered text get erased once i give the input to next field or perform any action.

Selenium Code:

```
   if(!(e.getCellData("Security",11,i).isEmpty())) {
        WebElement locator = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("fisnIssuerShortName")));
        locator.sendKeys(e.getCellData("Security", 11, i));

        List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = d.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-menu-item-wrapper']"));

        for (WebElement option : optionsToSelect) {
            System.out.println(option);
            if (option.getText().equals(e.getCellData("Security", 11, i))) {
                option.click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
     <tr>
      <td class="label" align="left" width="30%">FISN -Issuer Short Name</td>
        <td align="left" width="10%">
          <b> : </b>
         </td>
         <td width="60%">
           <input type="text" name="fisnIssuerShortName" maxlength="15" size="70" value="" onblur="setFISNComponent('fisnIssuerShortName');" id="fisnIssuerShortName" class="textField ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off">
            (Abbrev)
           </input>             
         </td>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The input you work with has an `onblur` event set. The `onblur` event occurs when an object loses focus. Probably you need to do any additional action to call it as it does not get fired when you use sendKeys. To do it try one of things

1. add click to any other element on the screen. For example click on the second input before entering any value to it. Or just click at any element that does not fire any event, any simple div or span would work
2. call an onblur event of an element via javascript after entering text to it

   `locator.sendKeys(e.getCellData("Security", 11, i));
   ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].onblur();", locator);`